# Как поменять value текстовой формы так, чтобы отмечались соответствующие значения в checkbox'е?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день, как на `jquery` сделать так, чтобы при вводе числа в `<input type="text">` руками, программа выделяла бы нужные варианты ответов в checkbox'е (в соответствии с введенным числом)?

Вот код:

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="ch1" value="1">Кошка</br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="ch2" value="2">Собака</br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="ch3" value="4">Попугай</br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="ch4" value="8">Рыбки</br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="ch5" value="16">Рептилии</br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk3" id="ch6" name="ch6" value="0">ЖИВОТНЫЕ ОТСУТСТВУЮТ</br>
  <input type="text" id="result" value="19"></br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Кэшируем востребованные данные
let form          = $('form'),
    notFound      = form.find('#ch6'),
    allCheckboxes = form.find('.chk, .chk3');

$('#result').on('input', function(e){
  // Убираем все галочки
  allCheckboxes.prop('checked', false);
  
  // Пустую строку проверять не будем
  if(this.value.trim() === '')
    return;
  
  // Ищем чекбоксы с нужным значением
  let tmp = form.find(`[value='${this.value}']`);
  
  // Если такой (-ие) есть, отмечаем их
  if(tmp.length){
    tmp.prop('checked', true);
  }else{
    // Иначе выбираем тот, который показывает отсутствие животных
    notFound.prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

```css
input{outline: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="ch1" value="1">Кошка</br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="ch2" value="2">Собака</br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="ch3" value="4">Попугай</br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="ch4" value="8">Рыбки</br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="ch5" value="16">Рептилии</br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk3" id="ch6" name="ch6" value="0">ЖИВОТНЫЕ ОТСУТСТВУЮТ</br>
  <input type="text" autofocus id="result" placeholder="19"></br>
</form>
```

**UPDATE**:
Выбираем все пункты, значение которых меньше или равно введённому значению:

```js
// Кэшируем востребованные данные
let form          = $('form'),
    notFound      = form.find('#ch6'),
    allCheckboxes = form.find('.chk, .chk3');

$('#result').on('input', function(e){
  let value = parseInt(this.value, 10) || 0;
  // Убираем все галочки
  allCheckboxes.prop('checked', false);
  
  // Пустую строку проверять не будем
  if(this.value.trim() === '')
    return;
  
  // Ищем чекбоксы с нужным значением
  // Т. е. фильтруем все чекбоксы чтобы из значение было меньше или равно введённому числу
  let tmp = allCheckboxes.filter((_, e) => e.value != 0 && parseInt(e.value, 10) <= this.value);
  
  // Если такой (-ие) есть, отмечаем их
  if(tmp.length){
    tmp.prop('checked', true);
  }else{
    // Иначе выбираем тот, который показывает отсутствие животных
    notFound.prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

```css
input{outline: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="ch1" value="1">Кошка</br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="ch2" value="2">Собака</br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="ch3" value="4">Попугай</br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="ch4" value="8">Рыбки</br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="ch5" value="16">Рептилии</br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk3" id="ch6" name="ch6" value="0">ЖИВОТНЫЕ ОТСУТСТВУЮТ</br>
  <input type="text" autofocus id="result" placeholder="19"></br>
</form>
```

Comment: слишкам сложна.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Хотел ещё стили прокомментировать, но влом :)

Comment: @avdemidov, спасибо тут выражается в плюсах и принятии ответа.

Comment: @Other, а как сделать так, чтобы введя число например 25, он выдавал все галочки суммарно по value

Comment: @avdemidov, это как?

Comment: @Other, например введя число 27, отметятся соответственно пункты 1, 2, 4, 5, а если 31, то все

Comment: @avdemidov, сделать легко, как - домашнее задание :)

Comment: @Other, кому то может и легко, но js сложен тем, что в нем трудно найти ошибку в отличие от того же php, что явно усложняет жизнь во время изучения

Comment: @avdemidov, что там, что там выстрелить в ногу себе легко, но это не значит, что изучить нельзя.

Comment: @avdemidov, так?

Comment: @Other, немного не то что я хотел, но вы мне и так достаточно помогли, буду разбираться

Comment: @avdemidov, раз уж начали - говорите что не так, подскажу.

Comment: @Other, у вас получилось, что введя число я получаю все варианты, value которого меньше введенного числа, а мне нужно, чтобы введенное число было суммой value, отмеченных галочкой пунктов

Comment: @avdemidov, Тогда раскладывайте введённое число на существующие слагаемые.